# JPA validation - OneToOne to same table

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, validation, jpa

I just enabled the JPA validation in eclipse and in shows me some errors (The code is actually running fine).

I have an article entity and it holds a refrence to the next article and the previous entity (of the same type). The validator complains with the message:

```
Column "nextArticle" cannot be resolved on table "article"
```

What does this mean exactly? The SQL table has the columns as well. I tried also to map the variables to each other with the "mappedBy" and "JoinColumn" annotation, but was not able to resolve the validation error.

That's the class and validation error:

[image]

And that' the mapping:
[image]

**Edit:** Tried the suggestion from anttix: The columns in the table are named "nextArticle_id" and "prevArticle_id", so I came up with that code:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "prevArticle")
@JoinColumn(name = "nextArticle_id")
public Article getNextArticle() {
    return nextArticle;
}

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "nextArticle")
@JoinColumn(name = "prevArticle_id")
public Article getPrevArticle() {
    return prevArticle;
}
```

But the validator complains now about the "mappedBy" annotation with the message:

```
In attribute 'prevArticle', the "mapped by" attribute 'nextArticle' has an invalid mapping type for this relationship.
```

**Edit 2:** I found the solution. I had to tell the validator the names of the columns in the actual database with the @Column annotation like this:

[image]

Comment: Remove mappedBy from relations that are backed by "real" columns. However there is really no need for two foreign key columns to implement the relationship. Please work through the wikibooks link, it explains in detail how these relations work.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse can't find a column called `prevArticle` in the table. You should specifiy the column name for nextArticle and create a bidirectional relation with prevArticle to indicate that it does not need a foreign key column of its own.

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "next_id")
private Article nextArticle;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "nextArticle")
private Article prevArticle;
```

You can omit the `@JoinColumn` from `nextArticle` if you want, but I would keep it there to make it clear which relation "owns" the foreign key column.

See also:

- http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToOne

Comment: I tried that, but it did not really work -> updated my post with the result

Comment: You did not pay attention to the example. There is no mappedBy attribute on a relation with `@JoinColumn`

Comment: Its the same if I use your example, but I guess, I need the mapping in both directions